# How to create column which automatically calculates average from another table's columns

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a web application where I would display table with name of the company and their rating according to users. It would be much easier for me if there would be a column with average rating for all companies which automatically updates when new entry is made.
For example, let say that I have Companies table:

```
╔════╤═════════════════════╤═══════════════╗
║ id │ nameOfTheCompany    │ owner         ║
╠════╪═════════════════════╪═══════════════╣
║ 1  │ Computer Repair LLC │ John Doe      ║
╟────┼─────────────────────┼───────────────╢
║ 2  │ Unimatrix           │ Barrack Obama ║
╚════╧═════════════════════╧═══════════════╝
```

And Services table where every service is evidented and rated by users (idCompany is FK).

```
╔════╤═══════════╤═══════════════════════════════════════════════╤═══════════╗
║ id │ idCompany │ serviceType                                   │ userGrade ║
╠════╪═══════════╪═══════════════════════════════════════════════╪═══════════╣
║ 1  │ 1         │ Installing antivirus and antispyware software │ 3         ║
╟────┼───────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────╢
║ 2  │ 2         │ Replacing new HDD                             │ 4         ║
╟────┼───────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────╢
║ 3  │ 1         │ Replacing new RAM                             │ 1         ║
╟────┼───────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────╢
║ 4  │ 2         │ CPU Cleaning                                  │ 5         ║
╚════╧═══════════╧═══════════════════════════════════════════════╧═══════════╝
```

I want to make new column in first table to have this:

```
╔════╤═════════════════════╤═══════════════╤═══════════════╗
║ id │ nameOfTheCompany    │ owner         │ averageRating ║
╠════╪═════════════════════╪═══════════════╪═══════════════╣
║ 1  │ Computer Repair LLC │ John Doe      │ 2             ║
╟────┼─────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────╢
║ 2  │ Unimatrix           │ Barrack Obama │ 4.5           ║
╚════╧═════════════════════╧═══════════════╧═══════════════╝
```

Comment: You can use a trigger to update the column automatically whenever the other table is changed. Or you could just define a view.

Comment: First of all, I am a beginner :D. I've tried some stupid things like setting column's default value to be sql query which would gather data from another table. But obviously it's not working. Triggers and Views are new topic for me. I'll find tutorial for these and try something what @Abhay Saraf said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will have you result.

```
    select  c.*, avg(userGrade) as averageRating from table.company c join table.service s on c.id=s.idCompan group by s.idCompany;
```

You also can create view using this query.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can set a trigger when the event of adding a record to `Services` table. The trigger could cause a stored procedure to execute and update the `averageRating` in the `Companies` table.